# Spring Data JPA query doesn't work, column does not exists

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I use spring data jpa in my web-app, i have entity user

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Boolean enabled;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String userRole;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String password, String email, Boolean enabled, String name, String lastname, String userRole) {
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "users_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="users_id_seq", sequenceName="users_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

 //Other columns
}
```

And i have UserRepository interface which extends CrudRepository.
When i call method findAll in my Controller, I get this error

```
01-May-2016 22:45:58.674 WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
01-May-2016 22:45:58.675 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions Error: column user0_.id does not exist
  Position: 8
```

My spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.birthright.repository"/>

    <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.birthright.entity"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/AutoService"/>
        <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My table in postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE public."user"
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass),
  password character varying,
  email character varying,
  enabled boolean,
  name character varying,
  lastname character varying,
  user_role character varying,
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: I guess the column exists in your table?

Comment: Yes, and  i don't  know where the prefix "user0_." is taken.

Comment: It's just the alias used by hibernate to name your user table

Comment: Is there any reason why you've got the id-related annotations into the getter method and not in the field itself?

Comment: It's auto-generated entity by Java EE Persistence -> Import DataBase Schema. 
But now I tried to add an annotation @Table(name = "user", schema = "public"), and it worked. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Birthright Please, never use table names like `User`. You will have a lot of problems. Just `users`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`User` is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL. With a default naming strategy you, probably, had `User` table name.

Don't know why `@Table(name = "user", schema = "public")` works. Maybe PostgreSQL doesn't consider `public.user` as a keyword opposite `User`.

Please use plural names for tables. And using a system or subsystem prefix for a table name (`xxx_users`) is a good idea too.

A naming strategy can be used for such approach. Refer this as an example: [Hibernate5NamingStrategy](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/cfg/strategy/hibernate5/Hibernate5NamingStrategy.java)

An example of prefixes:
[StrategyOptions](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-core/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/cfg/strategy/StrategyOptions.java)

Comment: You're right. I remove these annotation and renamed table in the "users" and also all the work.

Comment: @Birthright It is very good. Check a naming strategy, our team uses it to  don't have such problems. Column naming can be error prone too.

Comment: "User is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL."... half a day wasted... Thank you for the rescue...

Comment: @PetrDvořák You are welcome. Maybe you will help me in the next life :)